# How to convert List<Map<String,String>> to Map<String,String> using java-8 lambda and stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have below list of Map.

```
Map<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<>(); map1.put("DAY1","40T"); map1.put("DAY2","60T");
Map<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<>(); map2.put("DAY5","70T"); map2.put("DAY6","90T");
Map<String,String>[] mapArr= new Map[] {map1,map2};
List<Map<String,String>> lstOfMaps =  Arrays.asList(mapArr);
```

How to convert the above `lstOfMaps` as `Map<String,String>` using java8.
Where Keys are DAY1,DAY2,DAY5,DAY6 and Values will be 40T,60T,70T,90T

I have tried in cople of ways but it was lengthy using a `for` loop. Trying to use lambdas and streams now.

Comment: Try with this: https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-convert-list-to-map/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to take the entry stream of each map in the list, flatten them into one stream, and collect that back into a map:

```
return lstOfMaps.stream().flatMap(map ->
    map.entrySet().stream()
).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```